# Guava Google using Reflections in java

Tags: java, spring-boot, guava, reflections

I am trying to use Reflections in my Java project (also using Spring boot), and I have to get all the classes of a package that implements an interface.

```
public static Object[] getClasses(String packageName) throws IOException
  {
    Reflections r = new Reflections(packageName);
    Set<Class<? extends EntityXML>> allClasses = r.getSubTypesOf(EntityXML.class);
    return (Object[]) allClasses.toArray();
  }
```

But it returns me always this error.

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.collect.Sets$SetView.iterator()Lcom/google/common/collect/UnmodifiableIterator;
        at org.reflections.Reflections.expandSuperTypes(Reflections.java:380)
        at org.reflections.Reflections.<init>(Reflections.java:126)
        at org.reflections.Reflections.<init>(Reflections.java:168)
        at org.reflections.Reflections.<init>(Reflections.java:141)
        at gcs.fds.focus.lib.utils.FindPackages.getClasses(FindPackages.java:14)
        ...
```

I try to import the google.guava package to avoid this error, and it fix it, but I would like not to import it, because it is a package without use in my project.

Any idea about how to avoid this error?

Comment: " it is a package without use in my project." the error message disagrees. It may not be used by *your* code, but it's definitely used in the project.

Comment: It's not about imports, it's about whether the google jars are in your build path, and your class path when you run the methods. Imports just provide shortcuts for type names in your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okey I solved!

I deleted the google.guava dependency, and I make a

```
mvn dependency:tree
```

where I could see that other of my dependencies imports also google.guava, but version 19 which I read that makes this conflict. (everit.json dependency), so I exclude the google.guava from this dependency and it works!

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.everit.json</groupId>
    <artifactId>org.everit.json.schema</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.0</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Well that's **one** way to do it. But since Reflections brings in Guava, it would be better to explicitly define a version. Otherwise the next time you bring in a dependency that brings Guava, you can run into the same issue again.

Comment: It's true, I have to avoid importing google.guava version 19

Comment: You don't have to. You could import a known working Guava version (something more recent) into your project instead. The whole problem is because you don't want to explicitly define a dependency, because you think it's not being used.